# Setting up storage system for dockerized julia app on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: julia, google-cloud-storage, storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed a `julia app` (build with docker) on kubernetes cluster (GKE) which uses local filesystem structure (it will create a folder "test" on homedir() to store the data). For local testing it works seamlessly.
As pods on kubernetes cannot store data for later access and are prone to data-loss. I am trying to setup a storage system for the kubernetes cluster so that my app can store files outside of pods.

I have few queries to clear:

1. Does the generic directory creation and adding files which I am using for local dev will work on cluster pods? An example of the storing data is shown below:

```
cd(homedir())
mkdir("test")
open("$(mkpath("$(joinpath(homedir(), "test"))\\$run_number"))\\$run.jls", "w") do io
        serialize(io, run_data)
end
```

2. What is the best option for storage on kubernetes? I am currently working on *persistent-volume* and *persistent-volume-claim* scripts using **persistent-disks**. This seems to be not working properly.

**Adding Yaml File**

```
---
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "app"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "app"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "app"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "app"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "app-sha256-1"
        image: "gcr.io/project-1234/github.com/user/app@sha256:b17b8159668d44fec3d"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: "autoscaling/v2beta1"
kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
metadata:
  name: "app-hpa-y3ay"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "app"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: "Deployment"
    name: "app"
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: "Resource"
    resource:
      name: "cpu"
      targetAverageUtilization: 80

---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Service"
metadata:
  name: "app-service"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "app"
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: "app"
  type: "LoadBalancer"
  loadBalancerIP: ""

---
apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "ingress"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: "app-service"
    servicePort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metdata:
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 100G
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: test-pvc
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "51"
    uid: 26-39-47-a1-00
  gcePersistentDisk:
    fsType: ext4
    pdName: test-disk
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard-rwo
  volumeMode: Filesystem
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100G
  storageClassName: standard-rwo
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: test-pv
```

**Update:**

Firstly I would like to present my findings for the `1st` question: From research it is noticed that the method used to write and read the data on local dev could be directly used on the cloud.

I have created a `persistent volume` and `persistent volume claim` for the app, as shown in the yaml. In most of the tutorials, implementation of this on one pod is shown, however, I have 3 pods running. Should I manually edit yaml for each pod or can I do it directly on the deployment ?
Thanks, look forward to the suggestions!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate what issue you faced when you were trying to use persistentVolume as storage on your application.

Please refer these documentation on [persistent volume](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes) and [various storage options on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/storage-overview)

Comment: @GoliNikitha thanks for the response. I have created a persistent volume and claim yaml files, the above yaml config give a glimpse of my implementation. However, my pods still cannot access the pv through pvc.

Comment: In Readwritemany mode the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes. PersistentVolume resources that are backed by Compute Engine persistent disks don't support this access mode .As you can't attach persistent disks in write mode on multiple nodes at the same time.Refer this documentation for more information on [access modes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#access_modes).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data on locally on the pod after deletion of the pod it will also be deleted
Best approach is use database/cloud-storage/filestore based on your requirement(GKE is not best for statefulset applications )

But if you still want to do that you should use something called stateful set in GKE refer this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for more information.